# Subscribe to any changes in a SourceCache?

Tags: c#, reactiveui, dynamic-data

There are two **SourceCache** as root sources: *SourceCache1* and *SourceCache2*.
I also have two **ReadOnlyObservableCache** derived from SourceCache1 and SourceCache2: *DerivedReadOnlyObservableCache1* and *DerivedReadOnlyObservableCache2*.

I would like to refresh DerivedReadOnlyObservableCache2 when **anything** is changed in SourceCache1 (or DerivedReadOnlyObservableCache1).

Is it possible to get notified when anything is changed in a SourceCache or ReadOnlyObservableCaches? I want to be notified when either an item is added, removed or any property is changed of an item in the collection.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. How exactly have you "derived" from `SourceCache1` to `DerivedReadOnlyObservableCache1` with the `SourceCache` and `ReadOnlyObservableCache` classes? If you use something like `Bind()` any changes is already "refreshing" the other list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is [ForEachChange()](https://www.reactiveui.net/api/dynamicdata/observablecacheex/9d42a004) that allows you to track the changes in an ObservableCache. For example:
`_sourceCache1.Connect().ForEachChange(x=>Debug.WriteLine($"{x.Reason}{x.Key}")).ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler).Bind(out _source1).Subscribe();`